# Type 'TodoModel' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I'm building a todo app with react-typescript. I'm new to this, I'm passing props to single todo component. But it's showing the same error. Pls help

```
type Props = {
  todo: TodoModel;
  todos: TodoModel[];
  setTodos: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<TodoModel[]>>;
};

const Todo = ({ todo, setTodos, todos }: Props) => {
  const removeTodo = (id: number) => {
    setTodos(todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText style={{ color: "#f1f1ef" }} primary={todo} />
        <IconButton>
          <DoneIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}>
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItem>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Todo;
```

[Here is the link to entire code...](https://github.com/amritpal7/react-todp-ts/blob/develop/src/components/Todo.tsx)

Comment: Please share at least a screenshot of the error

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad, I figured it out. I was passing the entire object instead of single todo property.

It should go like that...

```
 return (
    <div>
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemText style={{ color: "#f1f1ef" }} primary={todo.todo} />
        <IconButton>
          <DoneIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton>
          <EditIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <IconButton onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)}>
          <DeleteIcon />
        </IconButton>
      </ListItem>
    </div>
  );
```